# Segmentation fault in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I receive **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** when i run this code.

I know the cudaMalloc is the problem, but I have no idea how to solve it. I just started learning some CUDA programming and im not familiar with it. I'm working on wsl if it matters.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 20
__global__ void VectorAdd(int *a,int *b,int *c,int n){
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    if(i<n)
        c[i]=a[i]+b[i];
}
int main(){
    int *a,*b,*c;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&a,SIZE *sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&b, SIZE *sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&c,SIZE *sizeof(int));

    for (int i=1;i<SIZE;i++){
        a[i]=i;
        b[i]=i;
        c[i]=0;
    }

    VectorAdd<<<1, SIZE>>>(a,b,c,SIZE);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    for(int i=1;i<SIZE;i++){
        printf("%d \n",c[i]);
    }

    cudaFree(a);
    cudaFree(b);
    cudaFree(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An allocation created using `cudaMalloc` cannot be directly referenced from host code as you are trying to do here: `a[i]=i;`.  There is a CUDA sample code that is called `vectorAdd` and gives a typical way to handle this.  Have you looked at that sample code?

Comment: The posted code wouldn't have been able to print the `c[]` values out at the end, either.

Comment: If you want to use ordinary code to initialize your arrays, and ordinary code to print the sum back out (as you're trying to here), you're going to have to: (a) allocate both regular memory and Cuda memory (for the regular memory you can use either plain arrays, or call `malloc`); (b) initialize your host arrays, (c) copy from host to device using `cudaMemcpy`, (d) call your kernel to do the addition, (e) copy from device memory back to host memory using `cudaMemcpy` again, and finally (f) print out the result.

Comment: Thank you for you answers. I will study the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments already suggested, you have to initialize values for arrays `a` and `b` on the host, copy them to device array, and once computation is completed you have to copy data from `c` back to the host.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 20
__global__ void VectorAdd(int *a,int *b,int *c,int n){
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    if(i<n)
        c[i]=a[i]+b[i];
}

int main(){

    int *a,*b,*c;
    int *h_a, *h_b, *h_c; /*declare pointers to host arrays*/

    cudaMalloc((void**)&a,SIZE *sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&b, SIZE *sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&c,SIZE *sizeof(int));

    /* allocate memory for host arrays */
    h_a = new int[SIZE];
    h_b = new int[SIZE];
    h_c = new int[SIZE];

    /* initialize values on host arrays */
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        h_a[i]=i;
        h_b[i]=i;
    }
    
    /*copy data from host to device */
    cudaMemcpy(a, h_a, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(b, h_b, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    VectorAdd<<<1, SIZE>>>(a,b,c,SIZE);
    // cudaDeviceSynchronize(); /* this is not needed because cudaMemcpy implies sync. */
    
    /*copy results from device to host*/
    cudaMemcpy(h_c, c, SIZE*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        printf("%d \n",h_c[i]);
    }

    cudaFree(a);
    cudaFree(b);
    cudaFree(c);

    /* free host memory */
    delete [] h_a;
    delete [] h_b;
    delete [] h_c;

    return 0;
}
```

**Notes**

- For some reason you start iterating from position `1` instead `0` in you for loops! If this is wrong by accident I fixed it!
- `cudaMemcpy` always performs synchronization between host and device. So, `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` is not necessary after kernel invocation.
- To avoid explicit handling of separated host and device data, you could use `cudaMallocManaged` instead of `cudaMalloc`.